# What is this thing near a news presenter?

Tags: broadcasting

[image]

What is this thing (shown by the arrow) in front of news presenters? Sometimes (sometimes→as I've seen) they press a button on that.. What's it called? Its purpose?

Comment: Video of them pushing on it might help give context. The only thing I would think they would need to push would be some sort of interaction with a prompt machine.

Comment: Looks like a digital clock to me

Comment: @fredsbend what would pressing it do to a tele-prompter?

Comment: Pause or play the scroll. Sometimes the scroll moves too fast or slow, so you might need to adjust it mid-speech.

Comment: But usually someone off screen does it as they pay close attention to the speaker's pace. Having the speaker do mysterious things with an unknown machine distracts audiences, as clearly evidenced by your question.